# Why is one of my transactions using more gas when both carry out the same function of sending ether?

Tags: gas, testrpc, out-of-gas

Below are two functions that I have in a simple lease smart contract. I am running a TestRPC node with Remix on version 0.5.1.

When I call the terminate function, it executes and terminates the contract as it is supposed to, sending the balance of ether to the landlord. However the withdraw function is supposed to allow the landlord to withdraw without terminating the contract.

```
 function withdraw () public
    {
        emit withdrawn();
        address payable landlordAddpayable = address(uint160(address(landlordAdd)));
        landlordAddpayable.send(address(this).balance);  
    }

    function terminate() public
    {
        emit contractTerminated();
        address payable landlordAddpayable = address(uint160(address(landlordAdd)));
        landlordAddpayable.send(address(this).balance);
        //rents paid are forwarded to the landlord
        state = State.Terminated;
    }
```

Original code sourced from medium.com and altered

Thanks

Comment: The two functions do different things, so they consume different amounts of gas. Presumably the second consumes a lot more gas because it writes to storage. Does that help?

Comment: The second function works though which is what I'm confused about

Comment: Why are you confused that the second function works? Is there some reason you expect it to fail?

Comment: The first function is what causes the VM exception out of gas error which is why I'm confused as it does less than the second function which works fine. Additionally, both functions work fine once they are in the JavaScript VM, just not in the test network

Comment: So I think your question is: "Why does the `withdraw` function below cause an out-of-gas error on a test network, while the `terminate` function  does not? Both succeed using the JavaScript VM."

Comment: Please share enough code/process that someone can try to reproduce the problem. (Add the missing events, tell us what gas limit you're setting, etc.)

Comment: Also tell us what `landlordAddpayable` is (externally owned account or smart contract). If it's a smart contract, what does it do in its fallback function? Does it make a difference what order you try to call the above functions?